# May I use my former-yet-active email address of an institute as a contact channel in my current CV?

Tags: etiquette, cv, email

Since I was a master student in (the North American) X university, my email `roboticist@x.edu` has been still active, even though it is a couple of years that I have left that university. Now, I'm about to finish my Ph.D. in (the European) Y university, and Y will be immediately closing my current `roboticist@y.edu` upon my graduation. I have heard that writing an unprofessional email address, e.g., `roboticist@gmail.com`, in the contact information section of an academic CV does not make a good impression on readers. So, I am wondering whether I may use the still-active email of mine corresponding to X in my CV for that purpose. My main concern is two fold: whether or not I am allowed to do that in view of X, and whether or not it is ethically a sound decision because it can mislead readers thinking that I am currently affiliated with X.

PS. My question relatively resembles what are discussed [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109439/is-it-appropriate-if-my-current-affiliation-is-different-from-the-ending-of-my-e) and [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/134543/email-address-etiquette-which-address-should-i-use-to-contact-professors), but the difference is that those questions' contexts are paper affiliation and contacting professors, respectively. However, mine is about the contact information section of a CV.

Comment: *Immediately*? Not even forwarding

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-: They keep the email alive for about a month, but after that it will be deleted without providing any forwarding services.

Comment: Wow that's the harshest email policy I've heard of

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Industry will close your account the day you leave (if not sooner).

Comment: @user2768: My "industry" email and security badge were deactivated late morning on my last day (finally got all last-minute things taken care of and actually left around 4:30 PM that day in Sept. 2017), and all 5 of my university emails where I had previously taught were deactivated from a few weeks to several months after my last day, although in those cases we're talking about last days from 1996 to 2005 (so maybe the situation would be different now). Also, my Ph.D. degree granting university's email was probably deactivated soon after I left (late July 1993), although I had no way to know.

Comment: When people say they dislike an "unprofessional" email address, they do not refer to roboticist@gmail.com, which seems fine, but to catlover123@gmail.com or superman@gmail.com. Those would look unprofessional on a CV.

Comment: If those are real email addresses, you may want to replace the `@`s with `at`s to prevent spam

Comment: My undergrad university has a mail forwarding service for alumni, providing a academic (*.edu) address and sending to whatever email address you actually look at. Not all places do, of course. But, roboticist@gmail.com is not unprofessional at all.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Surely the bots have figured that one out by now

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms: They are not indeed!

Comment: @Louic Technically, if you're a veterinarian or someone who runs a cat shelter the former is fine. And maybe the latter is fine if you're affiliated with the DC "Universe". :)

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I actually asked about that on information security stack exchange, if I remember correctly the response was that most bots don't care enough to try anything more sophisticated :p

Comment: Do you have any way of knowing the email policy of X University?  Everything is moot if they also decide that a couple of years is long enough.

Comment: It is not always just username.  There are some domains where I would be taken aback to find a roboticist hosting email there: aol.com and hotmail.com for example.  Unfair of me, sure, but that's the truth.

Comment: "_My question relatively resembles what are discussed here and here, but the difference is_"... I disagree; I think these are just variations of a generic "How do I provide persistent contact details for professonal use?" question that comes up a lot. These days I can envision a CV with only links to Facebook or Linkedin profiles rather than any email address.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I can see no legal or ethical problem with using an email address from a former institution, as long as you are clear about your current affiliations in your communications.

That said, there may be better options:

- Professional societies often offer an option of an email address. As a roboticist, for example, you can almost certainly affiliate with the IEEE, whose excellent email service I use myself.
- One of your former institutions may offer an alumni email address (or at least forwarding service). I believe this is more common in the US than Europe, but it's fairly arbitrary which institutions do and do not offer this.

Both of these can typically be set up very quickly and also have the advantage of being permanent, even when you change institutions.

Comment: Aren't you required to be an IEEE member to apply for an IEEE email address?

Comment: @Opifex Yes, that's the "affiliate with the IEEE" bit of my answer.

Comment: Part of the enrollment process with the previous university would have included agreeing to the IT policies, which would almost certainly have included a clause about only using the services while enrolled with the university. Universities do not typically provide free email services for former students. The fact that the email is still active is most likely just an adminstration oversight. It could be removed at any time without warning.

Comment: @user1751825 That is only the case for some universities. My own alma mater, for example, has long had a fairly long, generous, and flexible approach to transitioning students off of its email.

Comment: @user1751825: Typically, universities which disallow using their email servers after you graduate will enforce this policy by disabling your email address.

Comment: I'm with @jakebeal : I have email addresses at MIT and ANU based purely on being an alum. Several universities provide an on-going email address to keep in touch with their alumni.

Comment: "_required to be an IEEE member_"... on the one hand, joining a suitable professional organisation will cost money; on the other it suggests a commitment to staying in the field that might play well in a job application...

Comment: @LouKnee IEEE also tends to encourage membership by giving member discounts to their conferences that are equal to the cost of membership. So for researchers who attend at least one IEEE conference annually, it's often effectively free.

Comment: @ jakebeal To me that sounds strange, as I pay dues personally but expect my employer to cover conference fees so I wouldn't benefit from the discount. OTOH for IoP at least the rate is hugely reduced if unemployed.

Comment: @LouKnee This will vary by employer. Many (including my own) will be happy to pay for a membership.

Answer (score 25):

I don't think the premise holds. I have been on the hiring committee for many post docs, and I have never heard anyone mentioning the email address of a candidate. I could just as well cook up an imaginary argument saying that a hiring committee will find it unprofessional that you use your work email to apply for a job (that also does not hold). I would probably not go for wildly inappropriate handles, but normal ones are not a problem.

If you don't like using your gmail in professional settings, set up an alternative. I use firstname@lastname.com (which just happened to be available), and it is easy to set it up to forward to gmail. So you don't even need a mail server of your own.

Comment: @Roboticist. Plus 1. I corroborate the answer. Nothing wrong on using your Gmail address in this scenario. Just avoid "crazyname at Gmail.com" and that's it. Or keep using the old one if you're sure it won't be suspended soon. Your current affiliation/status is in the cv body.

Comment: @Alchimista Yes; avoid both crazyname@gmail or name@crazydomain.

Answer (score 22):

You're overthinking this.

roboticist@gmail.com is just fine as a professional email address.

When people talk about unprofessional emails it's the bit before the domain that causes issues, not the domain itself (unless you've deliberately gone out of your way to pick an unprofessional one).

If you're unsure, you can always go with `firstname.lastname @ CommonlyUsedDomain`

Answer (score 6):

Leaving asside the issue of unprofessional looking free email services, the worst type of email to provide to a prospective employer, is an address which may stop working at any time.

It's likely the email address is still active simply because the system administrators haven't gotten around to removing it. If someone decided to do an audit of the email addresses, they would very likely delete all of the old addresses, without any warning.

You won't get in any trouble for continuing to use the email address, but it seems very risky to put it on a CV, since you have no way to know how long it will continue to be accessible.

it would be a bad look if an employer attempted to contact you, only to receive a bounce message stating that there is nobody at the university matching that address.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: Yes, you can, but, why not setup a permanent address.** E.g.,

```
robot@icist.com
```

You've already discovered that institutional email addresses don't serve you long-term, find yourself a long-term solution.

Answer (score 2):

> I have heard that writing an unprofessional email address, e.g., `roboticist@gmail.com`, in the contact information section of an academic CV does not make a good impression on readers.

I disagree -- having an `@gmail.com` email address is no issue at all if this is the most up-to-date way to reach you.

> So, I am wondering whether I may use the still-active email of mine corresponding to X in my CV for that purpose.

I think the drawbacks outweigh the benefits. The benefit is that if X is a super prestigious university, `roboticist@X.edu` carries some "weight" to it and sounds impressive. But the drawback is that this is very confusing because you aren't currently at `X`. Anyone reading this would assume you are still working at `X`, or at least recently graduated, whereas this is actually an institution that you left a long time ago.

> My main concern is two fold: whether or not I am allowed to do that in view of X, and whether or not it is ethically a sound decision because it can mislead readers thinking that I am currently affiliated with X.

Ethically, I think there is no issue, but I think it is not in your interest to use the old email address as I (and others) have argued.

Answer (score 1):

#### Get Your Own Domain

The ultimate solution to this problem is to have your own domain. It does not have to cost a lot. For really good hosting, on the order of $60 to $100 per year. If you don't need much in the way of hosting - i.e., a really basic domain with very little storage because you just set it up with one email address that forwards everything to your gmail address - then it can cost much less.

Some people think you can only do that if you have a web site. That is not at all the case, but if you want to have a web site (a virtual CV) you can do that too.

Depending on the domain you get (e.g., lastname.com), you may be able to share it with family as well. Most full hosting includes (effectively) unlimited email accounts, subject to storage limits (which don't apply if you are forwarding everything).

While it is pretty obvious that "real University accounts" are at the whim of the University and could change at any time, even "alumni accounts" that have a fundraising reason to exist (and therefore are not likely to disappear suddenly in the name of cost-cutting) could have problems. Plus some hosting platforms (free or paid) can change over time (e.g., Verizon moved their "free" accounts to AOL's system). If you own your own domain, you can always move it to a different host if you don't like the original host.

Comment: You can get a 10 bucks per year domain from Google with an easy integration into your private gmail.

Comment: To add to this, you can get a .com domain for about $8-10 per year, then use the free tier from ImprovMX to alias your custom email with your gmail account, allowing you to send emails from within gmail, and receive them there too.

Comment: @DavidWheatley There are a ton of different options, with costs varying depending on whether you need/want actual web server or just email, directly hosted email or just forwarding, quality of email spam filtering, etc. But whether it is $8 or $100, it is a relative drop in the bucket to have total control over your email and not be tied to a free account that may disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's more unprofessional to receive an important email at `roboticist@x.edu` but never see it because they've either shut down your account or you grow distant from it and stop checking.

An email bounceback is not guaranteed in the event your email becomes disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking this here. All you actually need is to present yourself as a reliable candidate. The contact in CV should work for them for longer time.

Using domain you are no more affiliated with may be frown upon. And noone can grant you will get the emails they wil send you anyway. You can read the email address average.joe@X.edu as "Average Joe is working/studying At X".

Using public domain is not badly seen unless it is pinky.panther@something, dragonslayer@something or name@ki11a11n00bs.com. Reasonable private address is as sufficient as the university one. if you cannot affiliate yourself with any university (because your studies are ending) there is no need to stress about that.

What you can actually do is using two contacts - one using Y.edu while you are still there  and private one when your studies end. The hint what one to use is in your CV anyway, or they will answer to both.